# Are the Kara no Kyoukai movies based off chapters from one book or separate books?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners

In the Kara no Kyoukai, each movie is referred to as a Chapter so I've been wondering if they all comes from a single book or separate books and when they say Chapter they are referring to the movie collection (like how some anime series use Chapter # instead of Episode #)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [Type-Moon Wiki](http://typemoon.wikia.com/wiki/Kara_no_Kyoukai#Novels) the chapters of the light novel are:

- Chapter 1 – Overlooking the Scenery (俯瞰風景, **Fukan Fuukei**) Thanatos
- Chapter 2 – Murder Speculation (Part 1) (殺人考察(前), **Satsujin Kousatsu (Zen)**) …and nothing heart.
- Chapter 3 – Remaining Sense of Pain (痛覚残留, **Tsuukaku Zanryuu**) ever cry, never life.
- Chapter 4 – The Hollow Shrine (伽藍の洞, **Garan no Dou**) garan-no-dou.
- Intermission - Kirie/Fujino (境界式, **Kyoukai Shiki**)
- Chapter 5 – Paradox Spiral (矛盾螺旋, **Mujun Rasen**) Paradox Paradigm.
- Chapter 6 – Oblivion Recorder (忘却録音, **Boukyaku Rokuon**) Fairy Tale.
- Intermission - Lio (境界式, Kyoukai Shiki)
- Chapter 7 – Murder Speculation (Part 2) (殺人考察(後), **Satsujin Kousatsu (Go)**) …not nothing heart.
- Boundary of Emptiness (空の境界, Kara no Kyoukai)
- Future Gospel (未来福音, Mirai Fukuin) recalled out summer
- Final Record (終末録音, Shuumatsu Rokuon) the Garden of Oblivion

And the [animated films](http://www.animenewsnetwork.com/encyclopedia/anime.php?id=7472):

- 2007-12-01 (Japan, Part 1 - **Fukan Fuukei**) (same as Chapter 1 of novel)
- 2007-12-29 (Japan, Part 2 - **Satsujin Kousatsu**) (same as Chapter 2 of novel)
- 2008-01-26 (Japan, Part 3 - **Tsuukaku Zanryuu**) (same as Chapter 3 of novel)
- 2008-05-24 (Japan, Part 4 - **Garan no Dou**) (same as Chapter 4 of novel)
- 2008-08-16 (Japan, Part 5 - **Mujun Rasen**) (same as Chapter 5 of novel)
- 2008-12-20 (Japan, Part 6 - **Boukyaku Rokuon**) (same as Chapter 6 of novel)
- 2009-08-08 (Japan, Part 7 - **Satsujin Kousatsu** [conclusion]) (same as Chapter 7 of novel)

So the movies' chapters refer to the same chapters from the light novel.

Comment: So the chapters all come from the same book?

Comment: @Memor-X by "book" you mean a single printed release or light novel series (which is just called "Kara no Kyokai")? Because the 7 chapters span 3 volumes, but are all part of the same series.

Comment: i though it was either a series of light novels or a single light novel, didn't know it was both so i'm probably referring to whichever the anime was sourced from, if there is even a difference between the light novels and the single printed release

Comment: @Memor-X The series was released as 3 volumes, I think the first covered chapters 1-3, then 4-5, then 6-7. I don't think the individual chapters were released individually, but I could easily be wrong.

Comment: The first 5 chapters were actually published on Nasu's proto-blog (whatever you called those back in 1998) prior to receiving a print run (as 2 novels, not 3, I believe split up as 1-5 and then 6-7) in I think 2001. Mirai Fukuin is also based on a sequel novel (also titled "Mirai Fukuin" and released in 2008, seven years after the first two).

Comment: Oh, I should add that KnK was later reprinted as 3 books on smaller paper (bunko), which were split up as you describe (1-3, 4-5, 6-7).

Comment: @senshin Ah, that must be what I was thinking about, I've seen pictures of those 3 volumes before, had no idea how any of the previous releases were done though I knew that there were other releases