# What is the reasoning behind Kara no Kyoukai numerical movie order?

Tags: the-garden-of-sinners

After planning to rewatch and seeing *Kara no Kyoukai Remix: Gate of Seventh Heaven*, it made me curious; if the chronological timeline is quite clear, why did they decide to kind of scramble the chronological order for the 1st to 6th movie? Aside from the direction, does it have any meaningful reasoning plot-wise than to do it chronologically?

Comment: Note that the movies are adapted from the light novel, and that's the order of the original chapters (reference: [Are the Kara no Kyoukai movies based off chapters from one book or seperate books?](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/5396/2516))

Comment: @AkiTanaka ah, I didn't know about this, thanks, now I feel my question is a duplicate

Answer (score 1):

Kara no Kyoukai was designed to be out of order, just like the movie Memento was designed to go backwards.

I watched it chronologically once, but it doesn't work very well. Some of the slower movies are used to set the mood early on, putting them where they are supposed to go chronologically wrecks the flow.